# undefined property error of objects returned by AJAX

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, dwr

I'm using DWR to write a AJAX.
The creator method is

```
 public ArrayList<CompanyRecord> step4QueryTable() throws JCoException
    {...}
```

The CompanyRecord class is

```
public class CompanyRecord {
private String Code;
private String Name;
public void setValue(String value1,String column1)
{
    if (column1.equals("Code"))
    {
        this.Code=value1;
    }
    else 
    {
        this.Name=value1;
    }
}

public String getValue(String column1)
{

    if (column1.equals("Code"))
    {
        return Code;
    }
    else 
    {
        return Name;
    }
}

}
```

In dwr.xml I configured the converter like below

```
<convert converter="bean" match="com.SCOfetch.CompanyRecord">
   <param name="include" value="Code,Name" />
</convert>
```

In JSP I create a method

```
function bclick(){
    var result=[];
    SAPget.step4QueryTable(function(data){
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
             alert(data.Code);
            }
})}
```

And alert message result is always undefined. What I missed?Can anyone help?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my CompanyRecord class is not a valid javaBean. I updated it and now it works.

```
public class CompanyRecord {


public CompanyRecord() {
        super();
    }

private String code;
private String name;
public void setValue(String value1,String column1)
{
    if (column1.equals("Code"))
    {
        this.code=value1;
    }
    else 
    {
        this.name=value1;
    }
}

public String getValue(String column1)
{

    if (column1.equals("Code"))
    {
        return code;
    }
    else 
    {
        return name;
    }
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```